# Conjectures on iterated polynomial maps on finite fields

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-dynamics

Let $p$ be a prime, and consider the sequence $x_0, x_1, \dots$ of elements of the finite field $\mathbf F_p$ given by $x_0 = 0$ and $x_{i+1} = x_i^2 + 1$ for all $i \ge 0$.  This sequence must eventually start repeating;  let's write $T(p)$ and $U(p)$ for the period and preperiod (resp.) of the sequence.

There's an informal idea, used for example as the basis of Pollard's Rho method for integer factorisation, that for a 'randomly chosen' prime $p$, $T(p)$ and $U(p)$ should behave like the period and preperiod of the sequence of iterates of a randomly chosen function $\mathbf F_p\rightarrow \mathbf F_p$.  For example, it's expected that the quantity $T(p) + U(p)$ (that is, the index of the first repeated value in the sequence) is comparable in magnitude to $\sqrt p$, exceeding $x\sqrt p$ with 'probability' $\exp(-x^2/2)$.

Question: Does anyone know of formal statements to this effect in the literature?  I'm looking for a conjecture that would imply the following (or something similar) as a special case:

> Notation. For each positive integer $M \ge 2$, let $X_M$ be a discrete random variable that takes values in the set of primes not greater than $M$, with all primes in $[2, M]$ being equally likely to occur.  Let $X_\infty$ be a continuous random variable on $[0, \infty)$ that satisfies $\mathbf P(X_\infty > x) = e^{-x^2/2}$.
>
> Conjecture. The sequence $$\frac{T(X_M) + U(X_M)}{\sqrt{X_M}}, \quad M \ge 2$$
> of random variables converges (in distribution, say) to $X_\infty$.

Similarly, one might conjecture that $T(X_M) / (T(X_M) + U(X_M))$ is, in the limit, uniformly distributed on $(0, 1]$, and it should be possible to make (not prove!) some sort of statement about the independence of $T(X_M) / (T(X_M) + U(X_M))$ and $(T(X_M) + U(X_M)) / \sqrt{X_M}$.

I've so far failed to find any concrete statements of this form in the literature.  Any pointers?

[It's difficult to know how to tag this.  I guess it's really about discrete dynamical systems; please retag as appropriate!]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"ds.Dynamical-Systems" and "nt.Number-Theory" are good tags. Another one you could add is "Arithmetic-Dynamics". You might look at the arithmetic dynamics bibliography that I've assembled at

http://www.math.brown.edu/~jhs/ADSBIB.pdf

and search for titles that include the words "finite field". (Sorry, it hasn't been updated in a while.)

I'll also mention the following three articles.

- H. Niederreiter and I. E. Shparlinski. Dynamical systems generated by rational functions.
  In *Applied Algebra, Algebraic Algorithms and Error-Correcting Codes* (Toulouse, 2003),
  volume **2643** of Lecture Notes in Comput. Sci., pages 6–17. Springer, Berlin, 2003.

(The summary says " "We consider dynamical systems generated by iterations of rational functions over finite fields and residue class rings. We present a survey of recent developments and outline several open problems.")

Here's a paper of mine which might be relevant, although the estimates are pretty weak:

- Variation of periods modulo p in arithmetic dynamics, *New York J. Math.* **14** (2008), 601-616.

And one more whose summary says "The orbits produced by the iterations of the mapping $x\mapsto x^2+c$, defined over $\mathbb{F}_q$, are studied. Several upper bounds for their periods are obtained, depending on the coefficient $c$ and the number of elements $q$."

- A. Peinado, F. Montoya, J. Munoz, and A. J. Yuste. Maximal periods of $x^2 + c$ in $\mathbb{F}_q$. In *Applied Algebra, Algebraic Algorithms and Error-Correcting Codes* (Melbourne, 2001),
  volume **2227** of Lecture Notes in Comput. Sci., pages 219–228. Springer, Berlin, 2001.

If you forward and backward reference these papers, you'll certainly find other papers dealing with iteration over finite fields.

Comment: Sir, are any stronger estimates of the sum you handle in your NYJM paper known?

Comment: @Superguy I'm not sure offhand, so I'd have to do a literature search. Have you tried searching for all paper that reference my paper? If you do, you should find papers that prove stronger estimates, if there are any.